# Accessing matches variables in Powershell

Tags: powershell, object, match, assign

This question is more about my understanding Powershell's objects rather than solving this practical example. I know there are other ways of separating out a page number from a string.

In my example I want to do this by accessing the object-match-value of the piped pattern match.

```
# data
$headerString = 'BARTLETT-BEDGGOOD__PAGE_5 BEECH-BEST__PAGE_6'
# require the number of page only
$regexPageNum = '([0-9]$)'

# split the header string into two separate strings to access page numbers
[string[]]$pages = $null
$pages = $headerString -split ' '

# access page numbers using regex pattern 
$pages[0] | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regexPageNum | Select-Object {$_.Matches.Value}
```

The output is:

```
$_.Matches.Value
----------------
5
```

Okay. So far so good. I see the page number of array member `pages[0]` But how do I take this value from the object? The following does not work.

```
$x = $pages[0] | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regexPageNum | Select-Object {$_.Matches.Value}
Write-Host "Here it is:"$x
```

Output:

```
Here it is: @{$_.Matches.Value=5}
```

Instead of assigning the value `5` to the variable `$x` Powershell assigns, what looks to me: a hash table with an object description as its only member?

But if I try to access my variable using "Brackets for Access" Reference: [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.2) Powershell indicates that variable $x is in fact an array.

```
x = $pages[0] | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regexPageNum | Select-Object {$_.Matches.Value}
Write-Host "Here it is:"$x
$y = $x[$_.Matches.Value]
Write-Host "What about now:"$y
```

Output:

```
Here it is: @{$_.Matches.Value=5}
InvalidOperation: 

Line |
  33 |  $y = $x[$_.Matches.Value]
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.

What about now:
```

Okay. At this stage I know I'm being silly. But the point I'm trying to make is: How can I retrieve the value I want when I'm done with the Powershell object?

Comment: you can access the value by ```$x.matches.value```

Comment: @Toni. No. That does not work. Please include your reasoning. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$x.{ $_.Matches.Value }` to access the value.

```
$x = $pages[0] | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regexPageNum | Select-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
$x.{ $_.Matches.Value } # This will print 5
```

ie, You would have to wrap the property name inside `{}` since the property name contains "."

Instead of this way, I would suggest you to create a calculated property using `Select-Object` which makes the code more readable.

```
$x = $pages[0] | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regexPageNum | Select-Object @{Name = 'PageNumber'; Expression = {$_.Matches.Value}}
$x.PageNumber
```

Comment: Thank you @Abdul Niyas. Your second example works. And googling "powershell calculated property" tells me what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Access matches in case of single match
$x = "red blue yellow green" | select-string -Pattern 'blue'
$x.matches.value
#Output
blue

#Access matches in case of multi match
$x = "red blue yellow green blue" | select-string -Pattern 'blue' -AllMatches
$x.matches.value
#Output
blue
blue
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a scriptblock as a parameter to `Select-Object` the return value will contain a property whose **name** matches the source code of the script block...

```
PS> @{ "aaa" = "bbb" } | select-object { $_.aaa; <# xxx #> }

$_.aaa; <# xxx #>
-------------------
bbb
```

In this pathological case, if I want to access the property I can't use the name in the default "dotted" notation because it contains reserved characters, *but* you can access it if you quote the property name:

```
PS> $x = @{ "aaa" = "bbb" } | select-object { $_.aaa; <# xxx #> }

# note the leading and trailing spaces in the string because the
# the original scriptblock source contains spaces between the "{" and "}"
PS> $x.' $_.aaa; <# xxx #> '
bbb
```

In your case you'd do this:

```
PS> $x = $pages[0] | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regexPageNum | Select-Object {$_.Matches.Value}

PS> $x.'$_.Matches.Value'
```

Other options work too:

```
$x = $pages[0] `
    | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regexPageNum `
    | Select-Object {$_.Matches.Value}

# get the property whose name is contained in the $name variable
PS> $name = '$_.Matches.Value'
PS> $x.$name
5

# the scriptblock gets converted into a string, and then that string
# is used as a property name
PS> $x.{$_.Matches.Value}
5

# note the whitespace in both scriptblocks has to match *exactly* otherwise the property name won't be found
PS> $x.{ $_.Matches.Value }
ParentContainsErrorRecordException: The property ' $_.Matches.Value ' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
```

### but...

There's an easier way - if you pass a **hashtable** to `Select-Object` instead of a scriptblock you can specify the name of the property - e.g.

```
PS> $x = $pages[0] `
    | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern $regexPageNum `
    | Select-Object @{ "l"="Count"; "e"={$_.Matches.Value} }

PS> $x

Count
-----
5

PS> $x.Count
5
```

References:

- [about_Calculated_Properties - Hashtable key definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2#hashtable-key-definitions)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. You make it clear & simple.